# how to recursively create nested list from string input

Tags: python, recursion, nested

So, I would like to convert my string input

```
'f(g,h(a,b),a,b(g,h))'
```

into the following list

```
['f',['g','h',['a','b'],'a','b',['g','h']]]
```

Essentially, I would like to replace all '(' into [ and all ')' into ].

I have unsuccessfully tried to do this recursively. I thought I would iterate through all the variables through my word and then when I hit a '(' I would create a new list and start extending the values into that newest list. If I hit a ')', I would stop extending the values into the newest list and append the newest list to the closest outer list. But I am very new to recursion, so I am struggling to think of how to do it

```
word='f(a,f(a))'
empty=[]
def newlist(word):
    listy=[]
    for i, letter in enumerate(word):
        if letter=='(':
            return newlist([word[i+1:]])
        if letter==')':
            listy.append(newlist)
        else:
            listy.extend(letter)
        
    return empty.append(listy)
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Your idea looks quite good. Can you add some output you are getting here.

Comment: Note: `list.append()` doesn't return anything.

Comment: note that your expected output is not a valid list (`'h'['a', 'b']`)

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! gog, you are correct, I wrote a typo in the expected list and updated it. Daaran, The output I am getting is [['a', ',', 'f', '(', 'a', ')', ')']]. I am having trouble appending my new list to a list created in the previous function call, so that is where i am having most trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite an interesting question, and one I originally misinterpreted. But now this solution works accordingly. Note that I have used list concatenation + operator for this solution (which you usually want to avoid) so feel free to improve upon it however you see fit.

Good luck, and I hope this helps!

```
# set some global values, I prefer to keep it
# as a set incase you need to add functionality
# eg if you also want {{a},b} or [ab<c>ed] to work
OPEN_PARENTHESIS = set(["("])
CLOSE_PARENTHESIS = set([")"])
SPACER = set([","])

def recursive_solution(input_str, index):

    # base case A: when index exceeds or equals len(input_str)
    if index >= len(input_str):
        return [], index
    
    char = input_str[index]

    # base case B: when we reach a closed parenthesis stop this level of recursive depth
    if char in CLOSE_PARENTHESIS:
        return [], index

    # do the next recursion, return it's value and the index it stops at
    recur_val, recur_stop_i = recursive_solution(input_str, index + 1)

    # with an open parenthesis, we want to continue the recursion after it's associated
    # closed parenthesis. and also the recur_val should be within a new dimension of the list
    if char in OPEN_PARENTHESIS:
        continued_recur_val, continued_recur_stop_i = recursive_solution(input_str, recur_stop_i + 1)
        return [recur_val] + continued_recur_val, continued_recur_stop_i
    
    # for spacers eg "," we just ignore it
    if char in SPACER:
        return recur_val, recur_stop_i
    
    # and finally with normal characters, we just extent it 
    return [char] + recur_val, recur_stop_i
```

Comment: This works pretty well! Thank you so much! Just need to find a way to remove the index in the final iteration. Thank you man

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your input is something like this:

```
a = 'f,(g,h,(a,b),a,b,(g,h))'
```

We start by splitting it into primitive parts ("tokens"). Since your tokens are always a single symbol, this is rather easy:

```
tokens = list(a)
```

Now we need two functions to work with the list of tokens: `next_token` tells us which token we're about to process and `pop_token` marks a token as processed and removes it from the list:

```
def next_token():
    return tokens[0] if tokens else None


def pop_token():
    tokens.pop(0)
```

Your input consist of "items", separated by a comma. Schematically, it can be expressed as

```
items = item ( ',' item )*
```

In the python code, we first read one item and then keep reading further items while the next token is a comma:

```
def items():
    result = [item()]
    while next_token() == ',':
        pop_token()
        result.append(item())
    return result
```

An "item" is either a sublist in parentheses or a letter:

```
def item():
    return sublist() or letter()
```

To read a sublist, we check if the token is a '(', the use `items` above the read the content and finally check for the ')' and panic if it is not there:

```
def sublist():
    if next_token() == '(':
        pop_token()
        result = items()
        if next_token() == ')':
            pop_token()
            return result
        raise SyntaxError()
```

`letter` simply returns the next token. You might want to add some checks here to make sure it's indeed a letter:

```
def letter():
    result = next_token()
    pop_token()
    return result
```

You can organize the above code like this: have one function `parse` that accepts a string and returns a list and put all functions above inside this function:

```
def parse(input_string):
    
    def items():
        ...

    def sublist():
        ...
    
    ...etc
    
    tokens = list(input_string)
    return items()
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Sorry, I am a noob to coding, so how do I start using these functions? Do I type item(tokens) for this code to start processing or something?

Comment: So, in other words, what do I need to input to start processing my string? Is the start function items(tokens) for example?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the expected answer using the following code but it's still in string format and not a list.

```
import re

a='(f(g,h(a,b),a,b(g,h))' 
ans=[]
sub=''
def rec(i,sub):
    if i>=len(a):
        return sub
    if a[i]=='(':
        if i==0:
            
            sub=rec(i+1,sub+'[')
        else:
            sub=rec(i+1,sub+',[')
            
    elif a[i]==')':
        sub=rec(i+1,sub+']')
    else:
        sub=rec(i+1,sub+a[i])
    return sub


b=rec(0,'')
print(b)
b=re.sub(r"([a-z]+)", r"'\1'", b)
print(b,type(b))
```

Output

```
[f,[g,h,[a,b],a,b,[g,h]]
['f',['g','h',['a','b'],'a','b',['g','h']] <class 'str'>
```

Comment: would it be possible to turn "[f,[g,h,[a,b],a,b,[g,h]]" into a list somehow? seems very close to what I want but it needs to be a list

Comment: yes i was trying to do that using json package in python but it's giving an error.